# Having difficulty in fetching data from two different database using subquery and insert it into new table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have to fetch some data (e.g. Email, ClientName, DOB, CNIC, ClientId) of the clients who's birthday lies on current date for some purpose, and then log/insert it into a new table "Birthday_Client". But i am getting difficulty in making query because of DB structure it is like this:

**DB-1 has tables Account and Client**

Account table has "Email, CNIC and ClientID" columns

&

Client table has ClientName column

DB-2 has table Client_Detail

Client_Detail table has DOB(i.e. date of birth) column

so i have to fetch the data of only those clients who's birthday is on current date and then insert this selected data into a new table viz Birthday_Client.
Please help!

**P.S. : For making things easy for you ClientID column is present in all the tables.**

Comment: Why not give it a try yourself?

Comment: With due respect i am not asking this question before trying myself.

Comment: is both db in the same server? if yes just select db1.dbo.columns, db2.dbo.columns from db1.dbo.Account join with db2.dbo.Client_Detail on your_key_to_join. if different server search for sql linked server

Comment: what query did you try? what difficulty did you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.Email,
       B.ClientName,
       C.DOB,
       A.CNIC,
       A.CLientID
FROM   [DB-1].[schema].[Account] A
JOIN   [DB-1].[schema].[Client] B ON A.ClientID = B.ClientID
JOIN   [DB-2].[schema].[Client_Detail] C ON A.ClientID = C.ClientID
```